# Google sheets image url to image in cell?

Tags: google-sheets

It is possible to convert url link to image in cells ?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pksp.png)

Comment: please explain your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will have to use the `IMAGE` formula - this will insert the image into a cell.**

As for your task, apply this into the cell where you'd like to have the image and then drag it down in order to apply it to the whole column:

```
=IMAGE(D1)
```

The syntax of the function is the following and depending on your needs you can customize the other parameters as well.

```
IMAGE(url, [mode], [height], [width])
```

#### Reference

- [Google Sheets IMAGE Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you so much it works =IMAGE(D1) will show image all columns thanks

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a data url?